# Can we kill sqlserver with deadlocks or bad request from nhibernate?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-2012

I am a accidental dba admin sometimes and I have this question :

When you have deadlocks or bad request on a mssql 2012 on a windows 2k12 . Is it possible the combo kill the mssql service ?
I have to keep one database up for a c# app using nhibernate and sometime things go wrong.
So wrong that the only solution is a restart of sql services or reboot.
When things go wrongs the ping to this server top 800 ms in lan and of course rdp connexion or sql login fail . Some idea ?

Comment: Deadlocks won't "kill a server", but it's possible to make a database and queries against such unusable by acquiring long locks (generally in conjunction with stricter transactions). Solution: fix the code.

Comment: Ok so i have to use script to monitor log or default trace log bad request ?

Comment: Finding out what causes the issue is always a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You have set trace flag **DBCC traceon(1222,1204)** in query.It will record deadalock both spid in errorlog or you can check using **sp_who active**.There is solution for such insert or deletion order should proper so deadlock will minimize.